# What’s the difference between SATA and SATA-II?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between SATA and SATA-II (3.0 GB)?](https://superuser.com/questions/14790/whats-the-difference-between-sata-and-sata-ii-3-0-gb)

I'm looking to replace my hard disk, which is a Seagate Barracuda 7200.11 ST3500320AS 500GB.

My friend told me to get a SATA HDD, not a SATA-II. What is the difference between the two? And is my old HDD a SATA or SATA-II?

The new HDD I'm looking at is a Seagate 7200.12 ST3500418AS, which the store assistant told me is a SATA-II. However, the Seagate website labels both as SATA only.

I'm afraid that I'll buy a HDD which is incompatible with my system, especially since I'm going to install Windows 7 on it and I previously had the problem of Windows (Vista) setup not recognizing my hard drive. Would the new HDD be compatible?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/14790/whats-the-difference-between-sata-and-sata-ii-3-0-gb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both drives you mention use SATA 3Gbit/s, which is sometimes called SATA Revision 2 (or SATA-II). SATA 3GBit/s *should* be backwards compatible with earlier SATA 1.5GBit/s hardware, but most hard drives also have a jumper to force the drive to use the earlier standard ([PDF](http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/desktop/Barracuda%207200.12/100529369b.pdf), see page 28). The problem could also be that Windows Vista did not by default have the correct driver for your SATA controller - this should be provided by your motherboard manufacturer.

Comment: Even if you wanted to buy a SATA Revision 1 hard drive, I don't think you'd be able to, unless you found someone with "new old stock" 250 GB drives from 4 or 5 years ago.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. 

The jumper has indeed been set on my old HDD, and it looks like a small block fitted over 2 pins. If my new HDD comes without the jumper set, and I do need to set it, can I just (carefully) remove the "block" from the old HDD and fit it over the 2 pins on the new HDD?

Also, I think my problem with the Windows Vista installation was solved after I set the SATA drives to AHCI in the BIOS before installation.

Sorry if my questions seem to easy for the exterts here, but I have absolutely no experience in hardware at all. :)

Comment: @Rayne Yes, the jumper from the old drive should work on the new drive. The new drive appears to have the same arrangement for forcing SATA 1.5Gbit/s: http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/desktop/Barracuda%207200.12/100529369g.pdf